# Prepare controller and http request to preocess request without returning value

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I have following method to get collection of cars:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Car>> GetCars(object car, CancellationToken ct)
{
      var uri = new Uri($"{_webApiUrl}Car/GetCars");
      using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
      {
          HttpContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(car), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
          var req = await httpClient.PostAsync(uri, content, ct);
          var response = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
          return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Car>>(response);
       }
}
```

In my service api in controller i have this to get it:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
public IActionResult GetBottleTypeById(Car car)
{
     return Ok(_carQuery.GetCars(car));
}
```

*Both things works great - no issues.*

Now i need to save the `Car` and i don't need to return something (eventually i could return true or false whether it was succesfull or not). The problem is i am not sure how `controller's` `method` should look like, if i do this way it says: `not all code path returns value:`

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
public IActionResult UpdateOperation(Car car)
{
      _carRepository.UpdateOperation(car) //UpdateOperation is void with try/catch - throw;
}
```

Same thing with `request`, how this should be accomplished?

```
public async Task UpdateCar(Car selectedCar, CancellationToken ct)
{
       var uri = new Uri($"{_webApiUrl}Car/UpdateOperation");
       using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
       {
           HttpContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(selectedCar), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
           var req = await httpClient.PostAsync(uri, content, ct);
           var response = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
           return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Car>>(response);
       }
}
```

*How could i prepare both things to make it work?*

Comment: Just to `return Ok()` without any value.

Comment: See the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#return-values

Comment: You still need to send an HTTP response back even if it's just a simple 200 OK, regardless of whether you actually send any data back. The client application will treat it as a timeout if no response is received, as it has no way of knowing otherwise. Just how HTTP APIs work. Generally, API controller actions are going to return some type of `IActionResult` or `Task<IActionResult>` if it's async. The built-in action results will probably serve you just fine in most scenarios (i.e. return `Ok()`, `BadRequest()`, `NotFound()`, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Just change your code to return `void`. ASP.NET is smart enough to just send `200 OK` if no exceptions were thrown out of a void method.

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
public void UpdateOperation(Car car)
{
      _carRepository.UpdateOperation(car) //UpdateOperation is void with try/catch - throw;
}
```

To make your calling code work, you don't need to receive anything but the HTTP response message from the server. Even if your method returns `void`, HTTP servers still send a status code (200, 500, etc.) and some headers for you to inspect.

Try this:

```cs
public async Task UpdateCar(Car selectedCar, CancellationToken ct)
{
       var uri = new Uri($"{_webApiUrl}Car/UpdateOperation");
       using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
       {
           HttpContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(selectedCar), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
           var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(uri, content, ct);
           if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
           {
               return;
           }
           else
           {
               // handle error
           }
       }
}
```